# PDFmake gives me an error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'autoPrint' on string

Tags: javascript, html, pdfmake

please let me know what am i doing wrong? I am getting an error in console:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'autoPrint' on string '123.pdf'
at u.open (pdfMake.js:134:10)
at generowanie_pliku2.html:56:36

my code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.62/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.62/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>

<script>
  var docDefinition = {
    content: ["First paragraph"],
  };
  pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).open("123.pdf");
</script>
```

i need pdf to show on other page. It does not work with 'download' either